# Search for a proof of Moser's inequality

Tags: analysis

In the Canadian Math Bulletin volume 5, page 70 (1962)(Here's the appropriate link https://books.google.je/books?id=gfAghT1swAQC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de#v=twopage&q&f=false) L. Moser and J.R Pounder from the University of Alberta proposed the following problem:

---

[image]

---

Now, this problem is equivalent to showing that: Given a trinomial $ax^2+bx+c$ with real coefficients and real roots, demonstrate that the following inequality holds:
$$a+b+c \leq \frac{9}{4} max (a,b,c).$$

Furthermore, I attempted to find a proof of my own and I clearly failed to come up with one, so I went searching on the web, from MathStackExchange to it's original source, unable to  come across any satisfactory findings.

And so ask for practically anything, it being a hint (which is preferable), a partial or a complete proof. I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Useless Hint: The trinomial with real coefficients has real roots iff $ b^2 \geq 4ac$.
(It's a useless hint since I expect you're familiar with it, but I'd also have expected that you would have written this down as part of showing what you tried to do.)

Hint: Condition on the value of $ \max(a, b, c)$.
Case 1: If $ b = \max(a, b, c)$, then show that $ 4ac \leq b^2 \Rightarrow a+c \leq b + \frac{b}{4} $.

Case 2: If $ a = \max (a, b, c)$, then show that $ 4ac \leq b^2 \Rightarrow b + c \leq \frac{5a}{4}$.

Case 3: If $ c = \max(a, b, c)$ is the same as Case 2.

Hence, conclude that equality holds iff $a:b:c = 1:4:4$ or $4:4:1$.

Note: Slight care should be taken when considering signs, especially when dealing with inequalities.

In the case where $a, b,c > 0$:

> Since $(a+c)^2 = 4ac + (a-c)^2$, thus $a+c$ would be maximized by 1/ Letting $4ac = b^2$, and 2/ Maximizing $|a-c|$. This is achieved with $\{a, c \} = \{ b, \frac{b}{4} \}$ and thus $ a+c \leq b + \frac{b}{4} $.

> $4ac \leq b^2 \leq a^2 \Rightarrow c \leq \frac{a}{4} \Rightarrow b+c \leq \frac{ 5a}{4} $.

Comment: Well, at first I considered the case where all $a,b$ and $c$ are non-negative, and knowing the obvious condition that $b^2 \ge 4ac$, I proceeded to bound from above the expression $\frac{a+b+c}{max(a,b,c)}$ using well known inequalities, like the CBS inequality, but that kept failing, because for one it was becoming increasingly difficult to fit the aforementioned condition to the whole puzzle, and secondly this problem completely drained all my excitement, so my will to continue was pretty much on life support at that point., and thirdly I had no idea how to expand this to negative cases.

Answer (score 0):

Proofs of generalisations of the result [are given](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=u6N0yfe69RcC&pg=PA259&hl=en) on pp.$259{-}263$ of the same volume of the same journal by J.D.Dixon.

Comment: I'm aware that J.D. Dixon generalized the result, but that won't cut it.

Comment: @Vaskara_GRek_O Why "won't cut it"? (Assuming that the proof is valid,) you get the conclusion when $n = 2$.

Comment: @CalvinLin That proof is way above me and just plugging $n=2$ into Dixon's argument makes it unnecessarily ugly and inelegant, when it is much simpler business, as you've shown in your answer. Also, quite embarrassingly, even though you provided me with a sufficient hint, I'm still struggling, which is humiliation of high degree on my part.

Comment: @Vaskara_GRek_O I've added more details. If you're still stuck, comment on my solution and explain what you've tried (even if it doesn't seem to you that it leads anywhere).